Script is not pulling in formula result
I have found this forum to be very helpful.. reading through other issues and finding my solution. So far, I haven't found a solution to these two problems.
This script is used to create a document from my spreadsheet. It works exactly as I expected, except for:

Dates/Times are being entered wrong on the new document. I see solutions but they confuse me how to incorporate them into my script.
The same script is not pulling the 'trip number' value from the trip number column. It has a complex formula to generate trip number as I need it in a particular format. Honestly, I don't know how the heck it works, someone else from a different forum helped with that issue.

I also have a create event script that uses the same sheet that is working perfectly. It sees the trip number and pulls it into the description of the event as expected.
Here is my test sheet.
Here is my code:
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1kOLZvB7ZEspV1TJQi5oih_ZKVQuzoI5m19gHjCz7atw');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1022a6xSO_Bh9zNilY2O6nb8dirHFJb8m');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Mirror');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
     if (index === 0) return;
     if (row[29]) return;
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[18]}, Trip Sheet` , destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();

    body.replaceText('{{tripcategory}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{group}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{pickuplocation}}', row[7]);
    body.replaceText('{{destinationname}}', row[8]);
    body.replaceText('{{destinationaddress}}', row[9]);
    body.replaceText('{{leadsponsor}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{leadsponsorcell}}', row[11]);
    body.replaceText('{{studentcount}}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{{adultcount}}', row[13]);
    body.replaceText('{{comments}}', row[16]);
    body.replaceText('{{tripnumber}}', row[19]);
    body.replaceText('{{departdate}}', row[21]);
    body.replaceText('{{departtime}}', row[22]);
    body.replaceText('{{checkIn}}', row[23]);

    doc.saveAndClose();
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 29).setValue(url)
        
  })
  
}

I've been reading pages and watching videos. I'm very confused and don't know anything about javascript or other forms of coding.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Only one problem per question please.

Just a thought, instead of using getValues)  try getDisplayValues().  You might have to alter your logic slightly for if (row[29]) return;.  Is row[29] true\false?

For row[21] and row[22] try new Date(row[xx])

As a developer, it is important to take the time to understand the fundamentals. If you don't know how something works, then, as evidenced here, you will be unable to fix it when it breaks and unable to improve it as you grow. You MUST take the time to understand the fundamentals. Start with the basics, then work your way up until you truly understand what you're doing. It's good that you're using SO and finding the answers helpful, but if you don't take the time to understand the answers then you won't be able to grow as a developer.    If you're determined to start here, maybe start by isola

Ok, so my advise is to keep the const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); line. Do not change it to getDisplayValues(), instead use the values to create and format the strings of text that you want as an output.
First in your mirror sheet use this formula for the cells U2 and V2 =ARRAYFORMULA('Form Responses 1'!E2:E) that way we make sure that the values in those cells are date and time values.
Then in your Google Apps Script code put the next lines before the body.replaceText block:
// we create a variable with the value of tripnumber turned into string as an integer value
var strtripnumber = Utilities.formatString("%d", row[18]);
// we create a variable that contains the date and time of departure
var ddate = new Date(row[20]);
// then use that variable to create two strings, one representing the date and one representing the time
var strddate = Utilities.formatDate(ddate, "GMT-5", "MM/dd/yyyy");
var strdtime = Utilities.formatDate(ddate, "GMT-5", "HH:mm");

After that, change the replaceText lines for tripnumber, departdate and departtime like this:
body.replaceText('{{tripnumber}}', strtripnumber);
body.replaceText('{{departdate}}', strddate);
body.replaceText('{{departtime}}', strdtime);

Keep in mind that I'm using the column numbers as they are in your test file, if you have a main file with the columns in different order you should change them.
